# Ask : Do While Loop multiple condition

Tags: c

```
char name[20]="";
char address [50]= "";

do{
    printf("Input your name [1..20] : ");
    scanf("%s" ,name);
    fflush(stdin);
} while(strlen(name)>20);

do{
    printf("Input your address [1..50|| must contain \"Street\"] : ");
    scanf("%s",address);
    fflush(stdin);
} while((strcmp(address,"Street")) == 0 || (strlen(address) > 50)  || (strcmp(address,"Street") != 0));
```

Hello guys, I'm still newbie in C and I want to ask about this code. I want to make a program that user can input string and must contain word "Street" and it can input until 50 characters if more than 50 characters or no word "Street" then the program will do the repetition, so my problem is when i input word "Street blah blah" (more than 50 characters) it's still show the output and didn't do the repetition, so is there any solution about this code or there is another solving that can make me help my assignment . Thanks , sorry for my bad english (I hope the answer is in C cause i'm still learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
while((strstr(address,"Street")==NULL || strlen(address)>50 ));
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Answer (score -1):

This part of code is wrong

```
while((strcmp(address,"Street")) == 0 || (strlen(address) > 50)  || (strcmp(address,"Street") != 0));
```

Because you wrote `strcmp(address,"Street") == 0 || strcmp(address,"Street") != 0` which will result in `true` always.

try using this

```
while((strstr(address,"Street")==NULL || strlen(address)>50 ));
```